# Freeradius radclient unsupported attribute

Tags: radius, freeradius, fortigate, captive-portal

I want to send disconnect-message to NAS using radclient program  but when I want to disconnect one user using this command

```
echo user-name=zaib | radclient -x   192.168.3.1 disconnect "muh"
```

the debug mod show this error

```
rad_recv: Disconnect-NAK packet from host 192.168.3.1 port 3799, id=78, length=50
    Error-Cause = Unsupported-Attribute
    Event-Timestamp = "Jul  3 2017 09:35:01 +03"
    Message-Authenticator = 0xd52977c552ae0a7c83bb32c2acc6d195
```

I using fortigate as NAS 
I searched alot about this problem but I did not find solution

Answer (score 0):

Check if attribute you are using is on that list: [FreeRADIUS Attributes](http://freeradius.org/rfc/attributes.html)

Comment: thank you for your replay which attribute you mean I want to disconnect one user using above command

Comment: update coa {
               User-Name = "%{User-Name}"
               Acct-Session-Id = "%{Acct-Session-Id}"
               NAS-IP-Address = "%{NAS-IP-Address}"
        }

Comment: please help me @mrc02_kr

Comment: According to [link](https://wiki.freeradius.org/protocol/Disconnect-Messages) try to write attributes to file and then try to disconnect user. Maybe attributes are case sensitive and you need to type "User-Name=zaib" instead of user-name=zaib. I don't know for sure because I always type it with uppercase :)

Comment: I writed the comman in upper case but the same result is appear

Comment: I don't know where is my wrong

Comment: Try this: 
[Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/UY35v5e8)

Comment: I am so sorry about my questions and thank you very much for your trying but unfortantly same error is appear